# How to transpose matrix using uBLAS?

Tags: c++, boost, matrix, transpose, ublas

I am a newbie in C++ Boost uBLAS library so I have a noob question - how to transpose a matrix using this library? I could not find question here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
C = boost::numeric::ublas::trans(A);
```

Documented (poorly) under [Overview of Matrix and Vector Operations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/operations_overview.htm#24transformations).

Comment: There is a little more info here http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_expression.htm (Section 4.2)